# Mining my own blockchain?

Tags: miner-configuration, cgminer, solo-mining

I have downloaded bitcoin-qt and it has downloaded what I understand to be the blockchain: blk0001.dat and one or two other files in the .bitcoin folder in my home directory.

If this is the blockchain, can I point cgminer (or some other mining program) at one of these files and have it mine from there?

If so, how?

Comment: Do you want to create your own blockchain (i.e. fork the blockchain) or just generally start mining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run the bitcoin-qt client and solo mine using cgminer you can do that you need to enable server mode and create an RPC username and password in your bitcoin.conf file.  This information will be fed to cgminer to connect to your local machine to do your mining.

However I do recommend that before you attempt to solo mine that you read a couple things.  First of all here is a list of pro's and con's of solo mining vs pooled mining.  https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Pool_vs._solo_mining  Secondly once you figure out what kind of hashing rates you can get from the equipment you are mining with and plug them into a Bitcoin mining calculator to see what your expected earnings are. I encourage you at this point to look at some [mining pools](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=41.0) because you can earn a much steadier amount over a longer period of time.